# If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then show that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then show that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$.

Note $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$.

I thought I could just prove $K$ is a subset of $HK$ and vice versa so as to prove it is a normal subgroup but then how to do this I have no idea because I keep getting $hk$ element again while trying to do so.

I just tried to implement the steps to find $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Does $HK$ mean the direct product of groups, normally written $H \times K$?

Comment: No, $H$ and $K$ are both subgroups of $G$ so it means $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}\subset G$.

Comment: You should fix your other question rather than make a new one.

Comment: I am new to this , today's my first day , someone put my question on hold cause I didn't show my idea , I tried to edit it but the on hold never went away, so I put a new one. Apologies .

Comment: It's fine. Welcome to the site. It's often useful when asking a question to put some effort in, in the form of telling us what you've already tried and what part of the question you are finding difficult. This helps us give you better advice, and also stops the site becoming a "do my homework for me" forum. The other question has now been reopened just fyi.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you've already shown that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

First, it is clear that $K$ is a subgroup of $HK$ because $K$ is a group and $k=ek\in HK$ (as the identity $e$ is in the subgroup $H$).

To check normality, we note that for all $g\in G$ we have $gK=Kg$ because $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. But then if $g\in HK$, then we must also have $gK=Kg$ because $g\in HK\subset G$.

Comment: What do you mean by checking normality?

Comment: Checking that the subgroup is actually a *normal* subgroup.

Comment: Ok thanks , I sorta feel like an idiot for asking that.

Answer (score 2):

$K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, i.e. $g^{-1}kg \in K$ for all $k \in K, g \in G$.

$HK=\left\{hk~|~h\in H, k \in K\right\}$ is a subgroup since $e = ee \in HK$, if $h_1k_1, h_2k_2 \in HK$ then $h_1k_1h_2k_2 = h_1(h_2h_2^{-1})k_1h_2k_2 = h_1h_2(h_2^{-1}k_1h_2)k_2 = h_1h_2k'_1k_2$ for some $k'_1\in K$ because $K$ is normal in $G$ and so $h_1k_1h_2k_2 = h_1h_2k'_1k_2 = (h_1h_2)(k'_1k_2) \in HK$, ie. $HK$ is closed under multiplication and $(hk)^{-1} = k^{-1}h^{-1} = (h^{-1}h) k^{-1}h^{-1} = h^{-1}(hk^{-1}h^{-1}) = h^{-1}k'\in HK$ for some $k' \in K$, i.e. $HK$ is closed under inverses.

We want to show $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$, i.e. $(hk)^{-1}k_1(hk) \in HK$ for all $k_1 \in K, h \in H, k \in K$. Expanding, we need $k^{-1}h^{-1}k_1hk \in HK$. You can use similar transformations as above to move the $k$ factors to the right-hand-side of the expression.

Comment: Because I'm a moron and got my normal subgroup definition back to front. I should have been moving the h's, not the k's.  Will fix.

Comment: Many thanks for the edit, Dan.  Next time I shouldn't so hastily attempt to answer a questions on concepts I just read about :-).